# Trimming input in bash/sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

My input looks like:

```
22/05/2016TAKEMEAWAY    nsorte dat TAKEMEAWAYd0 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2016TAKEMEAWAY nsorte dat TAKEMEAWAYd241  "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017TAKEMEAWAY nsorte her the TAKEMEAWAYd447020 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017TAKEMEAWAY   nsorte TAKEMEAWAYd115155 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017TAKEMEAWAY nsorte TAKEMEAWAYd6792 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017TAKEMEAWAY   nsorte TAKEMEAWAYd625385 "https://bears.com"
22/05/201TAKEMEAWAYTAKEMEAWAY 20 vBul Dogs (  Cinema TAKEMEAWAY)4154850 "https://bulldogs.com/ my cats"
22/05/2017TAKEMEAWAYTAKEMEAWAY 20 vBul Dogs    (Cinema TAKEMEAWAY)4154880 "https://cats.com/my dogs"
22/05/2017TAKEMEAWAYTAKEMEAWAY   20 vBul Dogs (Cinema TAKEMEAWAY)4154830 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017TAKEMEAWAYTAKEMEAWAY 20 vBul    Dogs (Cinema TAKEMEAWAY)4154820 "https://flowers.com"
22/05/2018TAKEMEAWAYTAKEMEAWAY 20 vBul Dogs (Cinema TAKEMEAWAY)4154810 "https://bulldogs.com"
```

I want the output with one space separating date on the left and number of bytes in the middle:

```
22/05/2016 0 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2016 241 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017 447020 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017 115155 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017 6792 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017 625385 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017 4154850 "https://bulldogs.com/ my cats"
22/05/2017 4154880 "https://cats.com/my dogs"
22/05/2017 4154830 "https://bears.com"
22/05/2017 4154820 "https://flowers.com"
22/05/2018 4154810 "https://bulldogs.com"
```

Does anyone know how to do it in `sed`?

Comment: try to select answers as correct answer as well as try to up-vote people whoever trying to help you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We really need a *"Givez mez the codez"* Stack Exchange for folks who want to dump requirements without making an effort.

Comment: The line ending with my dogs" there is a 7 missing is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is to substitute a pattern that starts with `TAKEMEAWAY` and ends with `TAKEMEAWAY` followed by anything that's not a digit and replace the entire match with a space:

```
sed 's/TAKEMEAWAY.*TAKEMEAWAY[^[:digit:]]*/ /g' your_file
```